# Is it normal for my masters advisor to ask me not to share code from my masters work with my PhD advisor, and not to continue with the same topic?

Tags: advisor, research-topic, conflict-of-interest

I have couple questions for you guys and I hope to find some answers here.

### Scenario:

I finished my master's degree with a thesis at school A.  During my master's program at school A, I was a research assistant for my thesis adviser (Let's call him Professor A). 
Now, I am applying to school B for PhD (because PhD isn't offered at school A) and I am hoping to work with Professor B who has a same research interest as Professor A.

Professor A has requested that:

1. I do not share any codes with Professor B.
2. Choose a research topic that is different from my master's thesis for the conflict of interest.

### Questions:

My questions are:

1. Is this understandable and typical situation for many students? What do you do about this?
2. Do I need to completely change the trajectory of my PhD research topic from Master's and start a new topic in the same research area?

*Edit:
We are in the US.
Codes were collaborated. And already received my masters.*

Comment: Is the software public domain, property of school A, your property, or what? That depends on School A's policies and the relevant laws.

Answer (score 6):

II don't know anything about the law in your country, but I think that the request of Professor A has a weak justification:

1. As lang as *you* wrote the code in the course of your master
   program, your advisor has no right. The algorithms should be considered as public domain (unless you've
   signed an NDA). It is different, if (parts of) the code are done by
   others.
2. Being a master student does not constitue an employment relation. There is simply no base for any restriction to your further academic career.

Beside of this, I consider the behaviour of Prof. A (given you've presented all facts) as a bad academic style. Knowledge exchange, a.o. by exchange of people is a well established academic method. To answer your direct questions:

1. While conflicting loyalty may be a typical problem, I've never heard that a colleague of mine issued such request. Your course of actions depends (of course) on practical issues, too: Is there any danger that Prof. A prevent you from getting the master degree? If so, explain the situation to Prof. B and try to reach an agreement that you "officially" apply after you get your degree.
2. As I explain above: IMHO **no**. I would be a waste academic
   resources, i.e. your knowledge and abilities. (Beside of this, it is
   always a good advice to at least widen your area of expertise as
   well as include at least few topics that are totally new for you: It
   make you a better researcher)

Comment: While I agree with the second half of this answer, the first half contains several inaccuracies. I suggest you [edit] to correct (or remove) those parts.

Comment: "As long as you wrote the code in the course of your master program, is should be considered as public domain" - This is just not accurate. With a few exceptions (e.g. [employee of US government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_status_of_work_by_the_U.S._government)), code is owned by either the author of the code, or by their employer or someone else who has arranged ownership (e.g. through a contract). It is _not_ in the public domain. (Saying it is in the public domain means that _nobody_, including the author, owns the code.)

Comment: Also, regarding "Being a master student does not constitue an employment relation" - The OP was a research assistant for the masters advisor. In some circumstances, a research assistant job is an employment relation.

Comment: @ff524: It depends what "owning" means. In my country, there is a difference between the intellectual property (who can claim to have written the code; this right is not transferable), and usage right (who may use it). The OP ask for the second (usage). Unless specified otherwise, any document that is study-related would be public. This may be different, if the OP wrote the code *in her/his function* as RA (what is **not** related to the status of a Master student)

Comment: "Public domain" means that the intellectual property belongs to the public, not any individual. If the intellectual property is owned by an individual and they also _license_ it in such a way that others can use it, it is not in the public domain. See answers to [this question](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/55/does-open-source-qualify-as-being-part-of-the-public-domain) for further clarification.

Comment: @ff524: As I stated, the law is different in my country (that was the reason for my disclaimer at the start); US law does not apply all over the world. The OP does not provide an information on the country she/he studies. However, even if the concept of PD is different, the software is probably not owned by Prof. A, unless it was subject of the OP's RA activity.

Comment: My explanation of what "public domain" means is not US-specific. Regardless, if you are trying to say that the work should be publicly available, or that some usage rights should be granted to the public, but don't necessarily mean that the student relinquishes intellectual property rights, you should [edit] your post to say that, rather than using the phrase "public domain" which has legal implications that you don't seem to intend.

Comment: (Your profile says you are in Germany. The meaning of "public domain" in Germany is very similar to its meaning  everywhere else in the world; it means that no individual holds the intellectual property rights to the work. It's also debatable whether the student's code _could_ be released into the public domain in Germany, even if he wants it to be, under some interpretations of German law it makes even less sense than in the US to say that it "should be considered as public domain." See [Gemeinfreiheit](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemeinfreiheit) on Wikipedia.)

Comment: Let me clarify. Codes were done as a collaboration between me and professor A. Also I already received my masters so there is no danger with my degree. Now, I want to respect the request. It looks like I can't share anyway because it was a collaboration. But what about the topic? I gained a lot of knowledge from my master's thesis and when professor A says, "choose phd research topic that doesn't overlap with the research that you did with me," what is a fine line between same and different topic? After all, I was anticipating to use my knowledge from masters thesis to phd research.

Comment: And we are in the US.

Comment: @ff524: You are right, I refer to "Gemeinfreiheit". Since you are able to understand German, please note the the second sentence in your reference: "[...] public domain is similar but not identical to [...] Gemeinfreiheit." In Germany, any idea or theory of an exam thesis is "gemeinfrei", f.c. [here, 5.a](https://www.hochschulverband.de/fileadmin/redaktion/download/pdf/infocenter/diplomarbeiten.pdf)

Comment: @davab: If the code is a collaboration, A has the same rights as you. Regarding the topic: If A believes that she/he has to keep your knowledge, maybe A can offer you a research position with better conditions than B.

Comment: Ideas and theories are in the public domain because copyright protection does not apply to ideas; copyright only applies to the _expression_ of the ideas in words, images, source code, or some other medium. (This is true generally around the world, and also in the specific context of a German thesis - see e.g. 5.b. of that document). So while the _idea_ may be in the public domain, the source code is not; copyright protections do apply to the source code.

Comment: @Matthias: problem is that there isn't a PhD program at school A. So I'm choosing school B.

Comment: @davav: Right, you've mentioned it, I forgot. The most PhD programs I know have the concept of a co-advisor (even from another school/university). Couldn't you convince A to be your co-advisor while B is your advisor?

Comment: @Matthias I suppose that is what I need to do. I need to sit down with Prof A and clarify the expectation and what I can do to work with him. If prof A doesn't agree on that, I guess I have to either choose different topic or burn the bridge (which I don't want to do).

Answer (score 3):

I think restricting the use of the code, if the advisor was a co-author, is a legitimate request (even if not protected by law, so you had in principle the option to - legally - ignore the request).

Forcing you to switch topics is not.

If you want to be cooperative with A, you could try to avoid using, say, "state-of-the-art" techniques which A has not published yet, until the publication is completed. But it is unreasonable of A to expect that you abandon a potential future career direction on their behest.

Comment: This might sound funny but What can constitute as a different topic?  How different of a topic can be regarded as  "different" in same research area?

Comment: Are you going to submit to A's request? Frankly, there are people that believe that a whole area belongs to them; while I do respect the work of PhD students in that I consider their topic to some extent out-of-bounds, as long as it is limited, but if it is a major field/principle/theorem (think, say, Riemann's hypothesis), they cannot expect to be exempt from "infiltration". Even less so, can an established scientist. I am not answering your question about "different topic" directly here, as it is too opinion-based, but perhaps it gives you an idea how to approach this question.

Comment: I think speaking with the professor to clarify somethings would be best for me.  To understand her intentions and limits that I would have